# Why do I need to press enter to see other client's input in a socket python server?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a chat system with sockets in python and I am unable to figure out how to automatically update an input on all client terminals. Currently, if one client types in a message, the other client needs to make an input in order to see the input of the other client. Any response is appreciated.

Server code:

```
import socket
import select

HEADER_LENGTH = 10

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1234

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)


server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))

server_socket.listen()

sockets_list = [server_socket]

clients = {}

print(f'Listening for connections on {IP}:{PORT}...')

def receive_message(client_socket):

    try:

        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

        if not len(message_header):
            return False

        message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())

        return {'header': message_header, 'data': client_socket.recv(message_length)}

    except:

        return False

while True:

    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)


    for notified_socket in read_sockets:

        if notified_socket == server_socket:

            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()


            user = receive_message(client_socket)

            if user is False:
                continue

            sockets_list.append(client_socket)

            clients[client_socket] = user

            print('Accepted new connection from {}:{}, username: {}'.format(*client_address, user['data'].decode('utf-8')))

        else:

            message = receive_message(notified_socket)

            if message is False:
                print('Closed connection from: {}'.format(clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')))

                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)

                del clients[notified_socket]

                continue

            user = clients[notified_socket]

            print(f'Received message from {user["data"].decode("utf-8")}: {message["data"].decode("utf-8")}')

            for client_socket in clients:

                if client_socket != notified_socket:

                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])

    for notified_socket in exception_sockets:

        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)

        del clients[notified_socket]
```

Client code:

```
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys

HEADER_LENGTH = 10

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1234
my_username = input("Username: ")

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))

client_socket.setblocking(False)

username = my_username.encode('utf-8')
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
client_socket.send(username_header + username)

while True:

    message = input(f'{my_username} > ')
    if message:

        message = message.encode('utf-8')
        message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
        client_socket.send(message_header + message)

    try:
        while True:

            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

            if not len(username_header):
                print('Connection closed by the server')
                sys.exit()

            username_length = int(username_header.decode('utf-8').strip())

            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode('utf-8')

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode('utf-8')

            print(f'{username} > {message}')

    except IOError as e:

        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Reading error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            sys.exit()

        continue

    except Exception as e:
        print('Reading error: '.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `input()` of any kind that blocks the thread. So you would have to wait on the `input()` to be given in order to `recv()` the message from the server. The way you typically solve this issue is by multi-threading. Using an extra thread to print the messages on your  client while listening for `input()`.

**For Example:**

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

def recieve_thread():
    #recieve the messages from the server by starting a new thread
    running = True
    while running == True:
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

            if not len(username_header):
                print('Connection closed by the server')
                sys.exit()

            username_length = int(username_header.decode('utf-8').strip())

            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode('utf-8')

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode('utf-8')
            print(f'{username} > {message}')
 
thread = threading.Thread(target =recieve_thread)#if your function has arguments you can pass them as 'args =(arg,)'
thread.start()
```

**Another thing to note:** you should always avoid infinite loops. Like `while True` since your process will run forever unless you use a os manager to stop it. I changed the  `while True` portion of your code and added a control variable :`running` so you can stop the program on certain logic.

Comment: I got the "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately" error. How do I fix this?

Comment: @oogabooga the only reason why you set the socket to `client_socket.setblocking(False)` was to not block the main thread , now you can remove that line. Blocking will not be an issue anymore since your receiving and sending on two different threads.

Comment: @oogabooga a non blocking socket reads the data(if its available) and if it isn't available it will throw an exception(the one you are getting). So you would need to either block by removing false blocking attribute or throw it in a try except and handle it. check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509245/python-socket-recv-exception